# Specify image in Dockerfile based on building client platform/architecture

Tags: dockerfile, macos

I have a somewhat specific, Swift-based problem.
It seems that none of the official Swift images on Dockerhub support the M1, and instead the only seemingly reliable arm64 Swift images are found at swiftarm/swift. This means that manifest querying will always fail for an M1 for something like `FROM swift:5.5.2`. Additionally, trying to get around this with `--platform=x86_64` the particular project I'm trying to run fails to compile due to an error with the Swift compiler in QEMU.
Is there a way to do something like

```
IF platform == arm64 FROM swiftarm/swift
ELSE FROM swift:5.5.2
```

or should I just build and push my own multiplatform image

Answer (score 1):

-`--build-arg       Set build-time variables` it is possible to build with arch parameter depending on this arch is whether host arch or docker image arch.

Answer (score 0):

It would be hacky, but you could `sed` it in with a wrapper script.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

platform=$(uname -p)

if [[ $platform == "arm64" ]]; then
    sed -i 's/FROM swift\:5\.5\.2/FROM swiftarm\/swift/' Dockerfile
fi

docker build ...
```